# Definir um campo padrão select html

Tags: html

Gostaria de saber como deixar a primeira opção de um combobox(em html) com a opção "Selecione"
E obrigar o usuário a selecionar pelo menos 1 campo na caixa de seleção.

Exemplo:

```html
<select name="endereco_estado">
  <option value="AC">Acre</option>
  <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
  <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Para obrigar o usuário a selecionar pelo menos um valor em *inputs* do HTML, você precisa usar o atributo *required*, da seguinte maneira:

```html
<select name="endereco_estado" required="required">
  <option value="AC">Acre</option>
  <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
  <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
</select>
```

Uma solução para adicionar essa primeira opção, usando **apenas** HTML (sem CSS nem JavaScript) seria usar uma *option* com os atributos *disabled* e *selected*. Isso faria com que ela aparecesse no topo, já que o atributo *selected* faz com que ela seja selecionada automaticamente, e não poderia ser selecionada pelo usuário devido ao atributo *disabled*:"

```html
<select name="endereco_estado" required="required">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione</option>
  <option value="AC">Acre</option>
  <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
  <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
</select>
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it](https://repl.it/@Jvsierra_/SmallTastyList#index.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado João!